# jPlayer - Use setMedia() to set the media URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, jplayer

I'm trying to use jPlayer under Firefox 3.6 (Ubuntu)

```
function loadmedia() {
  $('#jquery_jplayer_1').jPlayer('setMedia', {
    mp3: 'media/audio/04-Piste_4_1.mp3',
  });
}

$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#jquery_jplayer_1').jPlayer({
    ready: loadmedia,
    swfPath: 'static/jPlayer',
    errorAlerts: true,
    supplied: 'mp3',
  });
});
```

But it's telling me

> jPlayer 2.1.0 : id='jquery_jplayer_1' : Error!
>
> Attempt to issue media playback commands, while no media url is set.
>
> Use setMedia() to set the media URL.
>
> Context: play

And doesn't play the file

You check an online example [here](http://v8.westmill.net/jplayer_test/)

Comment: I have tried hard, but I cannot get this, or any implementation to work in either Firefox 3.6.22 or Chromium 12. Results of debugging: Mp3 files are not supported in FF, the `ready` event is never being called. When I attempt to open files of another type, even from sources, errors are showing up: `Media URL could not be loaded.\nCheck media URL is valid.\n\nContext:http://example.com/file.mp3` (FF and Chrome).

Comment: I also tried to change the `solution` property to 'flash, html' to force jPlayer to use flash but same problem. It works when you lanch manually `loadmedia()` multiple times.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main point of jPlayer is so that you can use html5 with flash fallback, so you should leverage the html5 of FF and chrome, not depending on it falling back to flash.

Firefox doesn't support mp3 on html5, they support ogg, which is better anyway. I always format each audio file I need to play for each browser, that way you can leverage html5 when its available, and you give your app a much better chance at loading the audio file, with 3 for each browser to choose from (not all get loaded, just the one it needs).

Use: .ogg for Chrome and Firefox, .m4a for Safari, and .mp3 for IE.
[See here](http://jplayer.org/latest/developer-guide/#reference-html5-audio-format)

Covert your audio files then try this:

```
function loadmedia(){
   $('#jquery_jplayer_1').jPlayer('setMedia', {
      oga: 'media/audio/04-Piste_4_1.ogg',
      m4a: 'media/audio/04-Piste_4_1.m4a',
      mp3: 'media/audio/04-Piste_4_1.mp3'
   });
}

$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#jquery_jplayer_1').jPlayer({
    ready: loadmedia,
    swfPath: 'static/jPlayer',
    errorAlerts: true,
    supplied: 'oga, m4a, mp3'//fyi, in your code you had a trailing comma here, that will break IE
  });
});
```

**EDIT:**

Saw this on the jPlayer site for the new audio demo: [Link](http://jplayer.org/latest/demo-01/)

> Note that the {wmode:"window"} option is set to ensure playback in
>   Firefox 3.6 with the Flash solution. However, the OGA format would be
>   used in this case with the HTML solution.

Comment: Interesting. I thought that HTML5 would always ask for oga and m4a. I had no idea that browsers have already planned to support different formats :( And I didn't know that trailing commas don't work on IE, good to know Thanks.

Comment: Update on Firefox: mp3 is now supported since version 22 (2013)

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in your code that is probably causing this behaviour:

You have:

```
mp3: 'media/audio/04-Piste_4_1.mp3',
```

It should be

```
mp3: 'media/audio/04-Piste_4_1.mp3'
```

So remove the comma.

Comment: that's not a syntax error, and I always include a comma after the last item in a javascript object in case I want to add another item and this way I don't forget about the comma